# VBS how to paste user input?

Tags: input, vbscript

I want to get my vbs program to ask for user input using the command

```
Sl = InputBox("type something")
```

I then need later on to write down the user input into a link like

```
WshShell.SendKeys ("www.")
WScript.Sleep 200
WshShell.SendKeys ("{&Sl}")
WScript.Sleep 200
WshShell.SendKeys (".com")
```

but I can't get it to work

Here is the complete code that I used:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000
test = InputBox("noget")
WshShell.SendKeys("^{Esc}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys ("" & test & "")
WScript.Sleep 200
```

Comment: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000
test = InputBox("noget")
WshShell.SendKeys ("^{Esc}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys ("" & test & "")
WScript.Sleep 200

Comment: That comment is supposed to tell us ... *what?* Please [edit] your question if you need to add more information.

Comment: Besides, `SendKeys` is a *terrible* way of automating stuff. Do not use it unless someone's forcing you at gunpoint. Not to mention that this looks very much like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You may want to take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Did you want to make a condition for user input that he must type an URL ?